# coreos etcd config using ignition

Tags: pxe-boot, coreos, cloud-init

I'm trying to boot coreos on my private cloud using pxe boot using [coreos official document](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/booting-with-pxe.html).

The process requires ignition file for cloud config, but I can't find a way to set some configuration tags like etcd in ignition.

I'd be glad if anyone can show me a way

Answer (score 0):

Write out a systemd "drop in" that contains your etcd config. Here's an example from https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/etcd-live-cluster-reconfiguration.html#change-etcd-cluster-size

```
[Service]
Environment="ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS=http://<PEER_ADDRESS>:2379"
Environment="ETCD_DISCOVERY=https://discovery.etcd.io/<token>"
Environment="ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS=http://<PEER_ADDRESS>:2380"
Environment="ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001"
Environment="ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:2380"
```

Write that out to `/etc/systemd/system/etcd2.service.d/10-customizations.conf`. More info here: https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-systemd-drop-in-units.html#override-only-specific-option